# How to convert Integer[] in spinner to int or Integer for calculate

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I'm a new students in android studio. I need you help resolve issue about spinner in JAVA

below is my code for create spinner and need to get value from spinner to calculate.

How to input code ?

```
    final Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spn);
    final Integer[] period = new Integer[]{12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, period);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code for calculate.

```
    int Result1;
    Result1 = (period / 12);
```

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibwvE.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. `period` is an array of `Integer` so it does not make sense to assign it to an `int`.Could you be more specific about what you want `Result1` to be ?

Comment: Yes. I think the compiler is pretty clear. `period` is an `Integer[]`, so what do you expect `period / 12` to be? Wat is an armchair divided by yellow?

Answer (score 0):

The period is an array.
You need to use it as "period[yourIndex]/12".

```
int result1 = period[0]/12 (this results on 12/12 = 1).
int result2 = period[1]/12 (results 24/12 = 2).
```

You can get index by spinner.getSelectedIndex() or some like this.